# How to convert SQL Server 2005 database file into Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you connect to sql server from Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123624/can-you-connect-to-sql-server-from-excel)

I have my application which I am saving data into SQL Server Express Edition.

I want to upload the same data in excel.

Please help if any tool available.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123624/can-you-connect-to-sql-server-from-excel

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to import data from Excel to DB: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686 
And to export from DB to excel: 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/08/sql-server-2005-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-microsoft-excel-datasheet/