# using excel in windows form application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel, c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

I want to create Windows based inventory application. I need to automate the manual entry in multiple excel spreadsheets, and in spreadsheet formula's are also used . values in sheets are interdependent upon formulas.

I want to use excel like tables and formulas in application. Is there any way of creating spreadsheet and assigning formula's to cell ?

Or  Any better alternative?

Comment: Better alternative? Yes a database. You are going to spend more time interacting with excel athn you are on the inventory functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Tony suggests using a databse is a far better idea. If you use a database then you can have excel sheets connect to this for other users to interact with.

[Can you connect to sql server from Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123624/can-you-connect-to-sql-server-from-excel)