# Monthly report automated with VBA + SQL Server Stored Procs?

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, vba

I am trying to completely automate this process, and I'm wondering if its viable or efficient to do in VBA.

Report process involves 2 files:  one sql file and one excel file.

SQL file has the algorithm, and the final step is a query who's result is then pasted into the excel file.

The algorithm is simpler(than what the audience might be used to) but has two "into" commands and several "update" commands.

1. Two "into" commands, the first grabs a small portion(constrained on first and last day of previous month) of a 500m+ record table.  The second joins the first table with an eligibility type table.

   2. After the second table is created, there is a series of UPDATE commands that change existing data of existing columns.
   3. Then a series of ALTER & UPDATE commands that add new columns to the [second] table and UPDATES them with desired data.
   4. the final step is a query who's results are copy-pasted into excel (as is, no formatting changes necessary).

I'm not too well-versed in VBA/VBNET nor TSQL stored procedures and dynamic sql, if the sql algorithm was a simple pull query with no table creation, I can build something to automate that.  But the SQL has 2 table creations, and about a dozen ALTER & UPDATE commands.

Am I stirring up the wrong nest?  Should I run it manually as is?

Comment: Without seeing the code this is anybody's guess. I suspect this process could be simplified quite a bit. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: **Guess what is my code** . There is no code in your Q so what you try so far? did you expect from us to guess too?

Comment: I appreciate the link and will try to meet those standards on any future questions.  

For this question, I didn't want anybody to spend too much time on it, I apologize for not including the code nor any self-attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do automate this. I created a report that ran two stored procedures and created numerous queries with temp tables including both update and alter commands then used VBA to run execute these and aggregate the data in the final summary sheet.

There is a ton of documentation out there. You can even pass your values to the stored procedure after the user inputs them.

I would add this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation to comment yet (need 50).

Comment: Is this an advice? a comment? or an answer?

Comment: I've did some research, but somehow erroneously felt this couldn't be done in a manner that is more efficient than manual execution.  

Now, I know explicitly its possible and that should be enough motivation to carry onward...

Comment: Sami - As I stated this was a comment but until just now I did not have enough reputation to leave a comment however I have had similar questions in the past so I felt my experience was noteworthy since Lee was simply asking if he was barking up the wrong tree or not.

Comment: @LeeY. - Try these links to start. [link1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad)   [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QbGoDJJuZ4) [link3](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-front-end-to-sql-server-2495398) [link4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123624/can-you-connect-to-sql-server-from-excel)  These should get you started.